# How do I prevent JWT attacks in Django using asymmetric encryption?

Tags: django, security, jwt, access-token, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm working on a web app using React for frontend and Django for backend.

Currently, I'm using django simple-jwt in for auth purposes, and the JWT access and refresh tokens are exposed in browser cookies, so anyone who gets their hands on these tokens can theoretically log in on behalf of the actual user.
I was wondering if there are ways to prevent issues like this, particularly using Django?

I was looking into proof of possession (PoP) tokens, but didn't see any libraries that support this functionality in Django. Are there ways to prevent this in Django?

Comment: FWIW, if you manage to steal cookies, then virtually any website is open to impersonation. And it's not a significant enough problem that you usually need to worry about it. As long as you prevent MitM attacks by using HTTPS, it's not a real world issue. If the computer itself is compromised and an attacker can read the cookies directly from the browser's storage, then they can probably also read the password directly instead.